# php Webserver on local machine. Pagekite error: FAIL: localhost:8080 is down

Tags: php, webserver, tunnel, pagekite

When i try to create a tunnel with `$enter code here pagekite.py 8080 xxxx.pagekite.me`  , and someone trys to connect, there is this error: (FAIL: localhost:8080 is down). I created the website on my local machine with `$ php -S localhost:8080`. When i try to connect to the server on my local machine with http://localhost:8080 the site works perfectly.